# Is there any reason to upgrade my battery size in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In Deus Ex: Human Revolution, only your first battery will recharge when having zero energy. So regardless of how many battery packs you have, you'll always need to scarf down energy bars or other nutrients to refill your energy level beyond the first battery. Due to this, I can't see any reason why I would ever want to spend praxis points to upgrade my energy.

What reason is there to upgrade my energy level, or am I correct in thinking it's a waste of points?

Comment: The only thing I found more having more battery bars good for was extended cloaking time (at the cost of lots of nutrients, obviously), but I only used that on the very last location of the game. Before that point I just had just maxed the recharging and was patient.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- sometimes extended cloak will buy you enough time to hack some computers (e.g. funicular)
- eliminating wasted energy - if you have only 2 cells and you eat nutrition which restores 3 cells, you'll waste up to 50% of energy

Answer (score 18):

Having a complete battery set is useful for when cloaking and when you need to perform multiple takedowns quickly.

Partially drained cells will recharge to full. For example if you have 4 cells and only use 1 and half cells when cloaked, the cell which was half used will recharge to full.

So unless you’re going to play the game in stealthily, spending most of the time the using the cloaking augmentation there is no real need to upgrade your battery size past 3 cells.

Comment: You can still eat nutrient bars when cloaked, which would once again make the extended battery life pointless.

Comment: However, abilities that use full bars (like takedowns) will not regenerate (beyond the first).

Comment: You shouldn't really need to do more than once takedown at a time IMHO.  You should be using your darts (and at some points, gas) as often as you can.

Answer (score 9):

I upgraded to max and maybe only once benefited from it when I was going for the pacifism when I was

> trying to save Malik.

The first points I spent were on maxing out my energy expecting for my energy to go all the way to the top and recharge. I didn't know that it wouldn't.

Had I of known that I would not have upgraded. Personally I think having 3 bars would be optimal. Allows you to do things without the need of immediately eating bars and you can use packs if you need.

Comment: Layke, you should make sure to use spoiler markdown (>!) in your answer when mentioning spoilers. Not doing so is acceptable is fine when answering certain plot related questions since it's expected any answers will have spoilers, but for questions such as mine you should always make sure to use spoiler markdown (>!).

Comment: I didn't actually know how to do that. Thanks and sorry to anyone who read.

Answer (score 3):

I can only imagine one way in which it would be useful.

If you have a CyberBoost Pack, this will recharge two batteries at once. If you only have one discharged battery, half that pack is wasted.

For the jar, it recharges three batteries, which means again if you have less than 4 batteries, you will waste charge.

If you only rely on bars, there is no functional difference.

Comment: Man... the CyberBoost Jar is one of the stupidest items in the game.  You can fill 3 batteries (which are mostly useless) but it takes up 4 slots of inventory and it doesn't stack.  You'd get more bang for your buck with the packs or individual bars.  At least those can stack up.

Comment: @JeffMercado True, true, but if you find one, might as well use it.

Answer (score 0):

Also depending on your difficulty setting and play-style; you may find it useful for multiple take-downs in quick succession without having to wait an extended period of time to recharge (which may or may not put you at risk depending on how you do things).